# Connection closed by remote server

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, visual-studio-2010, iis

hi 
i am using Windows XP SP3. IIS version 5.0

i have deveoped an web application with .net frame work 3.5 visual studio 2010

i have created a virtual directory for that web application

for the first attempt when i browse the virtual directory i works for some while and stops working.

when i again try to access the web site it gives the following mwssage

**Error!
Connection closed by remote server
You tried to access the address http://172.16.13.152/TestWeb/(S(oqgtlaaeiy5qgws3t0hexvyq))/Login.aspx, which is currently unavailable. Please make sure that the Web address (URL) is correctly spelled and punctuated, then try reloading the page.
Make sure your Internet connection is active and check whether other applications that rely on the same connection are working.**

i dont know what is the problem

Is this the problem with the IIS or is it the problem with my web.config file.

Comment: does any one knows whats the issue

Comment: Check the event log and do some google

Comment: how can i check the event log?

Answer (score 0):

Have you set any deny/accept security permissions in that directory's web.config file?  If so, that is probably what is eventually blocking the page request because you've logged in / haven't logged in / lost your session, etc.